# Does dynamically added script blocks onload event?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Given the code below it seems that `onload` event is blocked until dynamically added script will fully load (plunker is here http://plnkr.co/edit/BCDPdgCjPeNUmLbf7wNR?p=preview)

```
var $,
    s = document.createElement("script");
s.src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js";
document.documentElement.firstChild.appendChild(s);

window.onload = function () {
    console.log($);
}
```

If I remember correctly it used to be different few years back so is this the case with most of the browsers these days or I'm simply doing something wrong here?

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you want to wait until onload is fired, you should create and add the tag in the onload-function. Or are you looking for [defered](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script)?

Comment: I have a script in HEAD section of the page. It dynamically creates  another script as in my example. I'm trying to figure out if moving such a script to the bottom of the page will possibly slow down onload event. Moving it to the bottom of the page would possibly delay onload event it seems.